# Is there a way to progressively read through an array?

Tags: python

So I am attempted to progressively build an array. I am importing data from a text file then trying to add each line one by one to an array. I am trying to create multiple graphs from the values in this data file. The first graph would show the first data point, the second graph would show the first two data points, then the third would show the first three data points, etc.

I am still trying to get the array to work before I begin to graph it. Currently I get no output from the arrays, but the lines succesfully write to the new file I am writing too.

```
with open('test.txt') as file1: #open original file
    with open('graph.txt','w+') as file2: #create new file
        for line in file1:          

            file2.write(line)
            #split the lines into x and y variables
            x = [line.split()[1] for line in file2]
            y = [line.split()[1] for line in file2]

            print(x)
            print(y)
```

Comment: Did you really mean `x = [line.split()[0] for line in file2]`?  (note the array index of zero instead of one)

Comment: Can you provide a sample input file and the expected output of this loop? It's not clear just what list(s) (not arrays) you are trying to build.